anchor #[access_control] macro usage
edit
I made mistake on the check function placement. it should be out of the mod day_14 (not in the same mod with initialize function). after move out, it does compile and everything works.
the correct code
#[program]
pub mod day14 {
    use super::*;

    #[access_control(check(&ctx))]
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<OnlyOwner>) -> Result<()> {
        // ...
    }
}

// notice this fn should be placed out of mod day14
fn check(ctx: &Context<OnlyOwner>) -> Result<()> {
    // ...
}


I'm following the rareskills 60 days tutorials of solana.
on day14, it introduce the #[access_control] macro to check is signer is the owner of program.
here's the code
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("Hf96fZsgq9R6Y1AHfyGbhi9EAmaQw2oks8NqakS6XVt1");

// NOTE: Replace with your wallet's public key
const OWNER: &str = "8os8PKYmeVjU1mmwHZZNTEv5hpBXi5VvEKGzykduZAik";

#[program]
pub mod day14 {
    use super::*;

    #[access_control(check(&ctx))]
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<OnlyOwner>) -> Result<()> {
        // Function logic...

        msg!("Holla, I'm the owner.");
        Ok(())
    }

  fn check(ctx: &Context<OnlyOwner>) -> Result<()> {
      // Check if signer === owner
      require_keys_eq!(
          ctx.accounts.signer_account.key(),
          OWNER.parse::<Pubkey>().unwrap(),
          OnlyOwnerError::NotOwner
      );

      Ok(())
  }
}



#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct OnlyOwner<'info> {
    signer_account: Signer<'info>,
}

// An enum for custom error codes
#[error_code]
pub enum OnlyOwnerError {
    #[msg("Only owner can call this function!")]
    NotOwner,
}

it doesn't compile on my computer. the error says
error[E0061]: this function takes 1 argument but 3 arguments were supplied
  --> programs/day-14-owner-check/src/lib.rs:6:9
   |
5  |   #[program]
   |   ----------
   |   |
   |   unexpected argument of type `&'info [anchor_lang::prelude::AccountInfo<'info>]`
   |   unexpected argument of type `&[u8]`
6  |   pub mod day_14_owner_check {
   |  _________^
7  | |     use super::*;
8  | |
9  | |     #[access_control(check(&ctx))]
...  |
14 | |
15 | |     pub fn check(ctx: &Context<OnlyOwner>) -> Result<()> {
   | |________________^
   |
note: expected `&Context<'_, '_, '_, '_, OnlyOwner<'_>>`, found `&Pubkey`
  --> programs/day-14-owner-check/src/lib.rs:5:1
   |
5  | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected reference `&anchor_lang::context::Context<'_, '_, '_, '_, OnlyOwner<'_>>`
              found reference `&anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey`
note: function defined here
  --> programs/day-14-owner-check/src/lib.rs:15:12
   |
15 |     pub fn check(ctx: &Context<OnlyOwner>) -> Result<()> {
   |            ^^^^^ ------------------------
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0061`.
error: could not compile `day-14-owner-check` (lib) due to previous error

my versions are

solana v1.18
anchor v0.30.1

I figured the usage of access_control is updated. but I am very new to rust. could anyone explain how the latest macro is used in this example?
thank you very much in advance.

Stupid me. I made mistake on the check function placement. it should be out of the mod day_14 (not in the same mod with initialize function). after move out, it does compile and everything works.

could you add this as an answer together with the code snippet

Hi Jimii. sure,  I have edit my question
